# Is there a Catholic council that established the dogma that the eschaton is in "Heaven" rather than in the Promised Land?

Tags: catholicism, heaven, eschatology, ecumenical-council

I imagine that the details of the afterlife were disputed as have all points of doctrine. Was the matter settled into dogma at a particular Council? I'd like to find out the details of who championed which views and with what arguments.

Comment: Could you add some supporting citations that this is the Catholic position?

Comment: @bradimus  Actually, that is an assumption on my part since it seems to be a given. If it is not I'd like to know that too. Feel free to edit the question if you have any insight into where they actually stand on the matter. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I can offer much insight, but l suspect this may be one area where 'popular' Catholicism diverges from the official teaching.

Comment: Why do you think there would be any doubt about what "My kingdom is not of this world" ([John 18:36](http://drbo.org/x/d?b=drl&bk=50&ch=18&l=36-#x)) means?

Comment: @Geremia  The Greek has "ἐκ" which means "from" this world meaning it is of heavenly origin: "ἀπεκρίθη Ἰησοῦς Ἡ βασιλεία ἡ ἐμὴ οὐκ ἔστιν **ἐκ** τοῦ κόσμου τούτου· εἰ **ἐκ** τοῦ κόσμου τούτου ἦν ἡ βασιλεία ἡ ἐμή, οἱ ὑπηρέται οἱ ἐμοὶ ἠγωνίζοντο ἄν, ἵνα μὴ παραδοθῶ τοῖς Ἰουδαίοις· νῦν δὲ ἡ βασιλεία ἡ ἐμὴ οὐκ ἔστιν ἐντεῦθεν." The "Lord's Prayer" is "Thy kingdom come" not "Let us go to your kingdom". Also ... "The kingdom of the world has become that of our Lord and of His Christ, and He will reign to the ages of the ages." - Rev 11:15b

Comment: If you could cite that dogma it would be helpful as a point of departure.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast  Actually, I was kind of assuming there was one as I thought all points of doctrine were established top down. If there is none, then that's all I need to know.

Comment: *Is there a dogma that  says X* might be a better way to ask this, with "which council established this" embedded in the end of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that a belief in a new creation which would have some earthly aspect to it has never been abandoned, though this is not well-known.  See *The Catholic Encyclopedia* (1917) on the New Advent website under "Eschatology," the last paragraph:

> There is mention also of the physical universe sharing in the general consummation (2 Peter 3:13; Romans 8:19 sqq.; Revelation 21:1 sqq.). The present heaven and earth will be destroyed, and a new heaven and earth take their place.

Comment: Can you demonstrate the *dogmatic* nature of these beliefs (i.e. their origin)? The Catholic Encyclopedia is not a source of dogma in itself.

Comment: See Catechism of the Catholic Church, Section II, Chap. 3, Art. 12 VI, "Hope of the New Heaven and New Earth."

Comment: Thanks. CC 2042-2043 cites *Lumen Gentium* (par. 48) (from Vatican II). You may wish to include this as something of a more "dogmatic" nature.

Comment: It may be a teaching of the church, but I am not sure it is fair to call it a dogma.  This  may take me a few days to collect some further points to share with you, but dogma is a subset of the larger body of things that are teachings of the church.